# drawing colored bands around circle

Tags: qt, geometry

I am recreating this gauge in QT, and having trouble with the colored bands part. I want to be able to color the bands from any place on the gauge (Ex from 20 to 50).

[image]

The math is confusing, should I use a drawarc function?

The gauge circle diameter is 300, so I know the radius is 150:

This gauge has 101 possible values, 0 to 100, and has 270 degrees used

```
float totalRads = 2 * pi * 0.75; // total radians for 270 degrees
float valueRads = totalRads/101;
float startRads = (135 * 2 * pi) / 360.0; // start radian for "0" on gauge
```

The barwidth is the width I want the colored arc:

```
float startAngle = atan2(startpoint.x(), startpoint.y()); // ex 20 on gauge
float EndAngle = atan2(endpoint.x(), endpoint.y());       // ex 50 on gauge

painter.drawArc(barwidth, barwidth, 2 * (150 - barWidth), 2 * (150 - barWidth),
                       -angle1 * 16, angle2 * 16);
```

This is not working as I expect.

Basically it just draws a little segment in completely unexpected area of circle:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the angles wrong.

> The startAngle and spanAngle must be specified in 1/16th of a degree,
>   i.e. a full circle equals 5760 (16 * 360). Positive values for the
>   angles mean counter-clockwise while negative values mean the clockwise
>   direction. Zero degrees is at the 3 o'clock position.

So, if you want to draw an arc from 20 to 50 on your gauge:
3 o'clock position is 0 degree. This means 20 is on the opposite position = 180 degree.

> => startAngle = 16 * 180.

The 50 is 90 degrees clockwise starting from this position.

> => endAngle = -16 * 90.

Not too much to calculate. Certainly not with atan2.